# Pulling notification center on my app

Tags: iphone, nsnotificationcenter

I made a simple app and when I want to pull the notification center from the top - just the little tab of the Notification Center window is showing and I need to pull down again with another finger for displaying the whole Notification Center.

Is anyone familiar with this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I understood why... that's because my app is on full screen.
If i put a status bar, for example, it swipes down ok.